# kotlinpoet generate code to call builder class continuously

Tags: kotlin, javapoet, kotlinpoet

Now i can generate code like this

```
val builder = MyBuilder()
builder.setA()
builder.setB()
builder.setC()
val target = builder.build()
```

I want to generate code like under

```
val target = MyBuilder()
  .setA()
  .setB()
  .setC()
  .build()
```

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Generated code doesn't have to be beautiful.

Comment: But if you really want an answer, it might be useful to show the KotlinPoet code you have, what you tried to achieve this yourself, and why it didn't work.

Comment: you would be able to do something like that, but your `setX` functions would have to return the class itself, which is yucky. Another things you could do is `MyBuilder().apply { setA(); setB(); setX() }`. You'd probably want to replace the `;` with new lines, can't format comments sadly.

Comment: @Jorn thanks for your suggest, I just want to generate code trimly。now i use my first plan, call builder.setX line by line. it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the exact same result, `indent()` and `unindent()` functions can be used, but I would advise against it as stated by the others.

```
val codeBlock = CodeBlock.builder()
  .addStatement("val target = MyBuilder()")
  .indent()
  .addStatement(".setA()")
  .addStatement(".setB()")
  .addStatement(".setC()")
  .addStatement(".build()")
  .unindent()
  .build()
```